# Custom route not displaying 404 page on cpanel

Tags: php, routes, cpanel, shared-hosting, namecheap

I developed a php project, in the project I create a custom route to handle urls coming to my application. I use PHP inbuild server during the development, after I deployed it on shared hosting (cpanel), any url other than myurl.com is displyaing 404 error page.

Example

- If I request myurl.com/blog is showing 404 error

Normally, I usually accept any url and load page specified to this url.

Here is my route

```
$routes = [
    '/login' => 'sign-in.php',
    '/logout' => '/dashboard/logout.php',
];
```

I want to use urls like mydomail.com/ or mydomain.com/section or mydomain.com/admin,

and load page base on th url

Comment: Please take some more time to write up your questions, its hard to understand what exactly the problem is here. You are probably missing a .htaccess file to redirect all request to your index.php - pls use the search function to find out how to set this up, there are tons of answers on this topic already.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean I can't access the site with url like mydomai.com/section. Only the home page can be viewed

Comment: And what have you done to make the webserver _trigger_ your PHP script, when `/section` gets requested?